# Customize appendices environment to print 'Publications' instead of 'Appendices'

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I want to customize `\begin{appendices}` command to print 'Publications'. It works in the main document, however it is still writing 'Appendices' in the table of contents.

```
\renewcommand\appendixname{Publications}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Publications}
\begin{appendices}
 \includepdf[pages=-, offset = 0 0]{\Papers\text.pdf}
\end{appendices}
```

How can i also change the title in contents ?

[image] [image]

Comment: Can you make a MWE?

Comment: What @samcarter is asking for is a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: `\renewcommand\appendixtocname{\appendixname}` if you're using `appendix` package and having defined `\appendixname` already to expand to `Publications`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `\appendixtocname` is responsible for the title of the Appendix in the ToC.

It must be redefined with `\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Yournicetitle}` if it should be other than the usual `\appendixname`.

Please note that a change of `\appendixname` does not change `\appendixtocname`, however!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\appendixname{Publications}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{\appendixname}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Publications}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\begin{appendices}
  \blinddocument
% \includepdf[pages=-, offset = 0 0]{\Papers\text.pdf}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]