# Change font color of "Appendices" page that appears with the appendix package

Tags: fonts, color, appendices, appendix

I have the following minimal of code where I have some chapters and some appendices.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[toc, page, title]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\begin{appendices}
\include{appendix1}
\include{appendix2}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

This will insert a page that says "Appendices" before the appendices begin, such as the one below:

[image]

I have used a different font **color** for my chapter and section headings, so is it possible to change the font color of this page so that it says "Appendices" in a custom color (so that it matches my chapter and section headings)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem however a better solution may be available.

Based on:

[Customize appendices environment to print 'Publications' instead of 'Appendices'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355995/customize-appendices-environment-to-print-publications-instead-of-appendices)

adding the following in the preamble will work:

```
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{\color{DESIRED_COLOUR}{Appendices}}
```

For example, to change the colour to blue:

```
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{\color{blue}{Appendices}}
```